# Passing ("text"+1) argument to Strlen function in C. Why is Output 3?

Tags: c

I am having problem understanding why is the output to this argument to strlen function 3.

I tried changing values from 1 to 2,3. I tried changing "text" to "textt". 
The pattern i observed is that the output is like this 
number of characters in string - numerical value

for e.g.if I use 2 instead of 1. The answer is 4 - 2 = 2

for +1 it is giving 4 - 1 = 3.

I am getting confused with this. Please help me understand. 
Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Text";
    printf("%ld %ld \n", strlen(str+4), strlen("text"+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `"text"` creates a pointer to its first character and `"text"+1` creates a pointer to its second character, that is, a pointer to `"ext"` which is a string of length 3.

Comment: The pattern is obvious: you are asking for the length of a string which starts at the beginning of "text" plus the number you put, so with ("text"+1) you are actually adding an integer to a pointer, resulting in a pointer to the string "ext", whose length is 3.

Comment: Side note: `strlen` returns a value of type `size_t` so the format specifier should be `%zu` and not `%ld`.

Comment: regarding: `strlen(str+4),`  for a char array: "text" results in a pointer to the terminating NUL byte, so the resulting value will be 0

Comment: regarding:  *for e.g.if I use 2 instead of 1. The answer is 4 - 2 = 2*  This is a misunderstanding.  There is no '4' involved, rather the expression like: `"text"+2` actually means the address of `"text"` plus 2.  I.E. the address of `"xt"`  The function: `strlen()` returns the 'offset' from the current address to the trailing NUL byte.  Which in this case is `2`.  Suggest, always read/understand the details of any C library function(s) that you use.  This is done by reading the MAN page for the function(s)

Answer (score 6):

The syntax `"string_literal" + N` will result in a pointer `N` bytes up from the start of the literal. `"test"+1` points to the string `"est"`, which has length 3.